# Unity - coroutines got inaccurate with timing, want to get around

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, coroutine

I wish to move an object over time using `coroutines`. I wanted to get an object from point **A** to point **B** over say **2 seconds**. To achieve this I used the following code:

```
IEnumerator _MoveObjectBySpeed()
{
    while (TheCoroutine_CanRun)
    {
        if(myObject.transform.position.y <= UpperBoundary.position.y)
        {
            myObject.transform.position = new Vector3(myObject.transform.position.x,
                myObject.transform.position.y + Step, myObject.transform.position.z);

        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_smoothness);
    }
    TheCoroutine_CanRun = true;
    moveAlreadyStarted = false;
}
```

and the `Step` is calculated like

```
    private void CalculateSpeed()
{
    Step = _smoothness * allDistance / timeToReachTop;
}
```

where `allDistance` is the distance between the bottom and the top boundary.

`_smoothness` is a fix value. The thing is, the **bigger** I get this value, the **more accurate** the time gets to get from bottom to up. Note that a small value here means smoother movement. This smoothness is the time the coroutine waits in between moving the `myObject`.
The time is measured like this:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
{
    DEBUG_TIMER();
}

#region DEBUG TIME

public float timer = 0.0f;
bool allowed = false;
public void DEBUG_TIMER()
{

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        StartTimer();
    }
    if (myObject.transform.position.y >= UpperBoundary.position.y)
    {
        StopTimer();
        Debug.Log(timer.ToString());
        //timer = 0.0f;
    }
    if (allowed)
    {
        timer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
void StartTimer()
{
    timer = 0;
    allowed = true;
}
void StopTimer()
{
    allowed = false;
}
#endregion
```

The results were:

When I wanted the object to reach the top under **1 second** and set the `_smoothness` to **0.01**, the time the `myObject` took to get to the top was **1.67** seconds. When `_smoothness` was **0.2s**, the time to actually reach the top was **1.04s**.

So why is this so inaccurate and how to make it work fine?

Comment: Check the `MoveObject` function in the answer from the duplicated question. Oh and `Time.deltaTime` should be used not `Time.fixedDeltaTime;`
 or  `WaitForSeconds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This smoothness is the time the coroutine waits in between moving the myObject

The mistake you're making is assuming that a co-routine waits the *perfect* time before executing.  Rather, it probably executes on the next *frame* after the timeout has finished.

Assuming you want smooth motion, you want to move the object *every* frame (e.g. in Update or co-routine that uses 'yield return null').

Note:  Each frame may take a different duration (consider 144fps vs 15fps), and you can discover this in Time.deltaTime . https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html